# Why Button disabled is not working after the page reload?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to disable the `submit` button , When the button is clicked and need to enable it after **10 minutes**.

I use the `local storage` to store the value.

The problem is, once the page is **reloaded**. I could not see the `Submit` button disabled. *Not sure ,why it happens*.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="someURL">
   <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
  const Button = document.querySelector("#btnSubmit");
     Button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        Button.disabled = true;
        localStorage.setItem("only_once", "true");
         setTimeout(() => {
             Button.removeAttribute('disabled');
          }, 60000);
      });
      if (!localStorage.getItem("only_once")) {
          Button.removeAttribute('disabled');
       }
```

I need to disable the `button` for **10 minutes**, even after the page is reloaded.

Could anyone please help?
Many thanks.

Comment: When the page is unloaded during the refesh your `setTimeout()` will be destroyed, and it will never occur. If you want this logic to cross page load boundaries you will need to use alternative logic. An example would be to store the exact date/time the button should be re-enabled, then when the page loads use a 1 second delay interval to check if that time has passed. If not, disable the button, if it has enable the button and cancel the interval. Also note that if your plan is to keep the time on the client-side it will be ridiculously easy to bypass. Do the checking server side.

Comment: Also, 60000ms is 1 minute, not 10 minutes

Comment: @Rory, Thanks for the explanation, could you please help me using code?

Comment: Sure, I added an example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page is unloaded during the refresh the handle to your `setTimeout()` will be destroyed and so it will never occur.

If you want this logic to cross page load boundaries you will need to use alternative logic. An example of this would be to store the exact date/time the button should be re-enabled, then when the page loads use a 1 second delay interval to check if that time has passed. If not, disable the button, if it has, enable the button and cancel the interval.

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#btnSubmit");
const buttonExpirationDataKey = 'button-disabled-expiration';

let startButtonStateCheck = () => {
  button.dataset.interval = setInterval(updateButtonState, 1000);
}

let updateButtonState = () => {
  let expirationDate = new Date(button.dataset.enabledAt);      
  if (expirationDate < new Date()) {
    button.disabled = false;
    clearInterval(button.dataset.interval);
  } else {
    button.disabled = true;
  }
}

let buttonDisableExpiration = localStorage.getItem(buttonExpirationDataKey);
if (!buttonDisableExpiration) {
  // no button state in localStorage, enable button
  button.disabled = false;
} else {
  // button state held in localStorage, check every 1s for expiration to enable the button again
  button.dataset.enabledAt = buttonDisableExpiration;
  updateButtonState();
  startButtonStateCheck();
}

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  button.disabled = true;
  let now = new Date();
  let expirationTime = 1000 * 10; // 10 seconds for this demo
  let expirationDate = new Date(now.getTime() + expirationTime);
  localStorage.setItem(buttonExpirationDataKey, expirationDate);
  button.dataset.enabledAt = expirationDate;
  startButtonStateCheck();
});
```

Here's a working example in a [**jdFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/v03ow9zq/), as SO snippets are sandboxed and disallow access to localStorage. To see the effect working, right click the lower right window and choose 'Reload frame'. The button will remain disabled, and will enable when the set expiration date passes. Note that I made the expiration time 10 seconds in the demo to make the effect easier to test, but this can easily be changed.

It's also worth noting at this point that if your plan is to keep the time-checking logic on the client-side it will be ridiculously easy to bypass. Make sure your server-side business logic validates the time interval between the current request and the users last legitimate request they made.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. Once we press the submit button,  even the form input fields `value == ""`. The submit button on clicking, gets disabled even with no input values. In that case, the submit button needs to be Enabled.  How can I do that? Could you please help? https://jsfiddle.net/1vgzj8oc/ @ Rory McCrossan

Answer (score -2):

I cant comment so I'll post here ,

You need to get the form elements and prevent default